# Download file without knowing its size

Tags: java, file, memory, download

I am downloading files using an URLConnection, DataInputStream and FileOutputStream. I am creating a huge byte[] with the size of the online file (with getContentLength()). The thing is that when I try to download huge files, I got an OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, which is a normal behavior.

Here is the code :

```
    URLConnection con;
    DataInputStream dis;  
    FileOutputStream fos;
    byte[] fileData = null;

    URL url = new URL(from);
    con = url.openConnection();                  

    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-store,max-age=0,no-cache");
    con.setRequestProperty("Expires", "0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache");
    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    con.setReadTimeout(30000);

    dis = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());

    int contentLength = con.getContentLength();

    //Taille connue
    if (contentLength != -1)
    {
        fileData = new byte[con.getContentLength()];

        for (int x = 0; x < fileData.length; x++) 
        {             
            fileData[x] = dis.readByte();

            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.onFileProgressChanged(x, fileData.length);
            }
        }
    }
    //Taille inconnue
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Attention : taille du fichier inconnue !");
        if (undefinedListener != null)
        {
            undefinedListener.onUndefinedFile();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.write(dis.readByte());
            }
            catch (EOFException ex)
            {
                //Fin
                fileData = stream.toByteArray();
                stream.close();             
            }
        }
    }

    dis.close(); 

    //Ecriture
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(fileData);  
    fos.close();
```

I've heard that I should split the file into chunks to avoid it. I know how to do this, it's pretty easy, but... how can I do this if the ContentLength of the file can't be red from the server (getContentLength() == -1) ? How should I split the file into chunks if I can't know the size of it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you use a `DataInputStream`?

Comment: Show the code that you're using now. There's almost certainly an easy solution, and it probably involves Apache Commons `IOUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a huge byte[] with the size of the online file

Why? You don't need a byte array the size of the file. That just wastes space and adds latency. Just read and write buffers:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

This works for any byte[] buffer of size greater than zero. I generally use 8192.

With URLConnection you don't need the content-length either: just read to EOS as above.

Comment: I did this way and it works, thanks :) The problem is that when you interrupt the download (by closing the window for example) you have a half-downloaded file left =/ How can I delete the file if the download has not been fully completed ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you should use a `DataInputStream` at all. Use [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
final Path dstFile = Paths.get("path/to/dstfile");
Files.copy(url.openStream(), dstFile);
```